When using Flex Wrap, how can the height be the same as the first line through min height?
Currently, I use Flex wrap to give a space when moving to the next line. However, if the height of first becomes longer, the height of the first flex wrap line does not become longer.
<div class="parent">
  <div class="unique-wrapper">
    <div class="unique_element">First</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">
    <div class="child">Second</div>
    <div class="child">Third</div>
    <div class="child">Fourth</div>
    <div class="child">Fifth</div>
  </div>
</div>

div {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.parent { 
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.unique_element {
  background-color: Crimson;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.unique-wrapper, .child-wrapper {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.unique-wrapper {
  flex: 3;
}

.child-wrapper {
  flex: 7;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: auto;
  background-color: Cornflowerblue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

my result
When increasing the height
As the height of first increases, the length of second and third must also increase, but in the current code, only first is longer. I searched and found that there is a way to add a hidden element, but I cannot give a classname to a specific element using data.map. What should I do?
the result I want
I would like to know what work is needed to make it look like the image above.

With flexbox you can't since it is not inherited. At best you could, perhaps, with CSS-Grid and subgrid but it would be better to just change your HTML.

It's not certainly possible but if you add equal height to each elements then height of all lines would be same.
